# call tooling API when using lightning component

Tags: apex, rest-api, tooling-api, httprequest, lightning-components

When I make request tooling API from Apex by using lightning component, the error `This session is not valid for use with the REST API` is responsed.
Also, the response status code is `401`, and status is `Unauthorized`.

How can we call tooling API without problem when we use lightning component.

By the way, when I use only "Debug - Open Excute Anonymous Window" in Apex,
I can get correct and expected response.

Below is the code that I tried.

```
req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/(Here is GlobalPickListId)?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
req.setMethod('GET');
httpreq = new Http();
res = httpreq.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From lightning session, you cannot invoke callout directly. You need named credential for that.

```
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v39.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/(Here is GlobalPickListId)?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
```

Create named credential for endpoint and use it.

**-----added-------**

Go to setup > Named credential as below:

[image]

Now, use the endpoint as below in apex:

[image]

You can use `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());` in same method.

For further details you can refer to: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm

Comment: Thank you for answer Should I edit endpoint code?

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.
Should I get permission from salesforce in Named credential to do that?

Comment: Not needed.....

Answer (score 0):

When you are making call outs from lightning context, the session Id you get doesn't have the scope or enough permission to make a callout to apis of Salesforce. You can do it in this way

1)  a.Create a connected app and register your own domain, and give auth provider as Salesforce
      b. Create a named credential, and and register your Salesforce domain

2) Before making a callout to tooling api, get session id by making callout to your Salesforce domain, and then use that session id to make a callout to tooling api

Comment: if possible, could you tell how to do it by apex code or some saledforce setting?